# Radio and checkbox inside label with Laravel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Is there any way to use `Form::label` with checkboxes and radio inputs to generate a markup that [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) suggests? The aim is to have input fields inside labels instead of attaching them with `id`s. I would like to avoid hardcoding the markup around `Form::radio`

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to extend the `Form` class and write your custom `input` implementation. Luckily bundle implementations already exist: http://bundles.laravel.com/search/tag/Bootstrap (bootsparks, bootstrapper)

Comment: I tried to figure out how would it work extending the Form class. Turns out I would rather just go for `<label>{{ Form::radio(...) }} Radio Label</label>` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write your own form macro and use that to build the html however you like.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros

Something like:

```
Form::macro('bootCheckbox', function($value, $label)
{
 $html = '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="';
 $html .= $value;
 $html .= '">';
 $html .= $label;
 $html .= '</label></div>'
 return $html
}
```

And then you can call it like this in your view:

`{{ Form::bootCheck('i_dont_know_what_value_youd_like', 'Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great') }}`

Of course you can pass any value you like to the macro and build whatever you want (given your code on the macro side is sound). 
The example above here should output a checkbox as you showed, but it's not too clean and I haven't tested it.

As for where to put the code, you can put it anywhere as long as you link it. My form macro's (which are a bit more extensive) live in /app/start/form_macros.php and required in /app/start/global.php by just adding `require dirname(__FILE__) . '/form_macros.php';` to the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Saint Genius for his answer, which led me in the right direction. +1

However, he is missing several semicolons, didn't include the name attribute on the checkbox field, and broke up the $html string over several lines, making it hard to read.

I have rewritten it a bit:

```
Form::macro('labelCheckbox', function($name, $value, $label)
{
    $html = "<label>
                <input name='$name' type='checkbox' value='$value' /> $label
            </label>";

    return $html;
});
```

And then in the view:

```
{{ Form::labelCheckbox('fruits', 'apple', 'Apple') }}
```

Comment: True dat, typed it off the top of my mind. But I think you're nitpicking a bit, I did state in my answer that the code is untested and not clean. Any dummy should be able to fix it xD

Comment: Yep, not going to edit it. It's not for copy/paste, just for example purposes.