# How can I include html within a form label using Laravel Collective?

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

Reading through [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361160/radio-and-checkbox-inside-label-with-laravel) I have read that I can create a new macro to create custom form inputs.

I am brand new to Laravel development (big surprise) & it seems a tad overkill for such a small thing. Is there a "simpler" way to have something like this:

**blade template**

```
{!!Form::label('firstName', 'First Name<sup>*</sup>') !!}
{!! Form::text('firstName', null, ['class'=>'required']) !!}
```

**html**

```
<label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="required">
```

Or, is this a case where I just write the html, and then use the form service to create the inputs?

Thank you for your patience and insight.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The simple way to do this is

```
{!! Form::label('labelFor','labelText',[],false) !!}
```

the last parameter is $escape_html which default value is "true".

Comment: This should be the selected answer, this is the proper, built in way to accomplish this.

Comment: I agree this is a better answer, with the caveat that the fourth argument is only available in 5.2+.

Comment: {!! Html::decode(Form::label('email', '<i class="fa fa-icon envelope"></i>E-Mail Address', ['class' => 'text-muted'])) !!}

Answer (score 5):

The `Form` class attributes will always be escaped (they were in Laravel 4 and still are with Laravel Collective's 5+ support), therefore no HTML is allowed. Since you're needs are so simple, I'd suggest just writing plain HTML.

If you want overkill, maybe something like this in your `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Form::macro('labelWithHTML', function ($name, $html) {
    return '<label for="'.$name.'">'.$html.'</label>';
});
```

Then, in your Blade templates:

```
{!! Form::labelWithHTML('firstName', 'First Name<sup>*</sup>') !!}
{!! Form::text('firstName', null, ['class'=>'required']) !!}
```

Comment: Personally I'd use plain HTML for the label - but still use Form::text for the input box. It adds the old input etc.

Answer (score 1):

{!! Html::decode(Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address', ['class' => 'text-muted'])) !!}

that is much better to fix these type of problems

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's late to answer, but you could do this:

```
{!! Html::decode(Form::label('firstName','FirstName: <sup>*</sup>')) !!}
{!! Form::text('firstName', null, ['class'=>'required']) !!}
```